# assigning values for specific td position using array in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query, where I want to display in one row for every Distinct proc.item_id.

> `$query =  mysql_query("SELECT proc.item_id AS proc_item_id, GROUP_CONCAT(proc.month_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS month_id,GROUP_CONCAT(item_quantity SEPARATOR ',') AS item_quantity,SUM(item_quantity) AS total_quantity,item.item_cost,item.item_desc FROM proc
>                           INNER JOIN item ON proc.item_id = item.item_id
>                           GROUP BY proc.item_id")or die(mysql_error());`
>
> This is for getting all months.
>
> > `$queryMonth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM month 
> >                                 ORDER BY month.month_id")or die(mysql_error());`
> >     
> >     `while($resMonth = mysql_fetch_array($queryMonth))
> >         {
> >             $month[] = $resMonth['month_name'];

```
}  

echo '<table border="1" align="center">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr><th rowspan="2">Item</th><th rowspan="2">Quantity</th><th rowspan="2">Cost</th><th colspan="12">SCHEDULE/MILESTONE OF ACTIVITIES</th></tr><tr>';
    foreach($month as $mName)
    {
        $m = substr($mName,0,3);
        echo '<th>'.$m.'</th>';
        $arrCtr++;

    }
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tbody>';
```

`
Then, I fetch the result for $query,

> `while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query))`
>
> > `{`
> >
> > > 

```
`$item_desc = $res['item_desc'];
    $total_quan = $res['total_quantity'];
    $cost = $res['item_cost'];
    $total_cost = $cost * $total_quan;
    $month_id = explode(',',$res['month_id']);
    $item_quan = explode(',',$res['item_quantity']);


 echo '<tr><td>'.$item_desc.'</td><td>'.$total_quan.'</td><td>'.$total_cost.'</td>';    

    echo '</tr>';       
} `
```

My question is: How can I add td for $item_quan? I want to use an array. $arr = array();
But using the values of array $month_id as the position of every $item_quan in $arr
example:

> `$month_id = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 4 )`
>
> > `$item_id = Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 5 )`
> >
> > > So when: `$arr[$month_id[0]] (where $month_id[0] = 3)` it should look like this:
> > >
> > > > `$arr[3] = $item_quan[0];`
> > > >
> > > > > then in  it will align on the 3rd table header of the months.

Please help me with this one! I was trying to figure it out for almost 3 days. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think want you want is to relate month index to quantity index with month value. try following snippet

```
$month_id = explode(',',$res['month_id']);
$item_quan = explode(',',$res['item_quantity']);
$array=array();
foreach($month_id as $i=>$m){
    $array[$m]=$item_quan[$i];
}
echo "<tr>";
  foreach($array as $k=>$v){
      echo "<td>$v</td>";
  }
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: We had the same solution!